# Secondary Index on Custom Java Object in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I have two classes.

```
class  A {

    String aName;
    B b;

    public A(String aName, B b) {
        this.aName = aName;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

class B {
    String bName;

    public B(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }
}
```

I am storing A as a set in Aerospike and **A.aName** is primary key. I want a secondary key on **A.b.** I have created index on A.b attribute and able to persist also. But search from the index is not returning anything. As per my understanding, Aerospike supports only three type of indexes: String, Numeric and Geo,. Is there any option for custom object.

Comment: Cross posted to Aerospike's Forums: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/secondary-index-on-custom-java-object/6485

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also index string, numeric and geo **within** different source types - basic (meaning just a bin with scalar data), list (so you can index strings or numeric data that is contained in a list), map keys and map values.

See: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html#secondary-index-key-source-type

You could model this in a few ways:

**As a map.** Let's assume that you store the value of A in a bin whose type is a map, it could have two map-keys - aName and bName. You can build a secondary index for string data on map values. Now, if you search for a specific bName you'll have this record come up.

More rationally you'd do the following **as separate bins**.

Assume that you use several bins, among them two bins to hold aname and bname. Their values are strings. You could now build a secondary index for string values and a basic index type (string data not contained in a complex data type such as list or map). You'd query for all the records where the predicate is bname = foo.

For a more complex situation one or more bname values map to a single aname, you'd actually model this **as a lookup table**.

Assume a set (table) called *users* holding records whose keys are the aname. A single key-value operation such as a read or an upsert works on a specific instance of class A, identified by a given *aname*.  One record in Aerospike per instance of A.

You have another set (table) as the lookup table, where for each unique *bname* you create a record. The specific *bname* is the key to this record. The value is the *aname*. So to find the record in the *users* set, you first look it up in the lookup table by the *bname*. You use the value of this record as the key for the *users* record for that *aname*.  This is the most common way of modeling this type of use case, **without a secondary index**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer post on Aerospike forum.

```
Binary blobs can be anything, there’s definitely no way to index that. If there is a particular field in your class you can pull out and set as a separate bin with a string/long type then that would work
```

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/secondary-index-on-custom-java-object/6485